# How to use time.sleep() to draw circles Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I wrote a program to explore Tkinter & try out object-oriented programming. My goal is to draw concentric circles, starting with the outside and moving in.

The drawing works fine, but my time-delay between circles isn't working. I can see the count-down (with `print`) but it doesn't draw anything until after the count-down ends.

Possibly this is related to the creation of the object? Nothing happens until the object is finished being created? IDK.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

size = 1000
myCanvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", height=size, width=size)

# draw circle
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, rt, dia, color, x=0, y=0):
        self.rt = rt
        self.dia = dia
        self.color = color
        self.x = x  # center cord x
        self.y = y  # center cord y

    def draw_circle(self):
        r = self.dia / 2
        up_left = (self.x - r, self.y + r)
        low_right = (self.x + r, self.y - r)
        cord = up_left + low_right
        self.rt.create_oval(cord, fill=self.color, outline="")


coord2 = 0, 300, 300, 0
#arc = myCanvas.create_oval(coord2, fill="blue")

def PickColor(r, g, b):
    r = r % 250
    g = g % 250
    b = b % 250
    return('#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b))

class ConcentricCircles:

    def __init__(self, rt, quantity):
        self.rt = rt
        self.quantity = quantity

    def draw_circles(self):
        q = self.quantity
        circles = []
        i = 0
        for c in range(q, 1, -1):
            time.sleep(0.005)
            incr = size/(1.5*q-0.001*c*c*c)
            print(c)
            circles += [Circle(self.rt, incr*c, PickColor(110, 15*c^3-c^2, 300*c^5-c^4), size/2, size/2)]
            circles[i].draw_circle()
            i += 1
            self.rt.pack()

a = ConcentricCircles(myCanvas, 30).draw_circles()

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it draws:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `sleep()` function, the application suspends updates to the GUI. This means that the drawing of circles is also suspended. But you can force the application to update the GUI before it continues with `update_idletasks()`, see example below. I chose to make the update in the `Circle.draw_circle()` function:

```
def draw_circle(self):
    r = self.dia / 2
    up_left = (self.x - r, self.y + r)
    low_right = (self.x + r, self.y - r)
    cord = up_left + low_right
    self.rt.create_oval(cord, fill=self.color, outline="")
    self.rt.update_idletasks()  # Updates the canvas
```

When you use `sleep()` the application is busy all the time it sleeps. You might want to research the `after()` function which schedules a function call but does not lock the app.